# How to store non utf-8 strings in mongodb using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, utf-8, pymongo

How to store non utf-8 strings such as "\xac\xbb,v\xc9o\xa8\x18\x89\x95\xd8K\x03AZ\xac" in mongodb using pymongo?

If I do it using the usual way, i get a error message "strings in documents must be valid UTF-8: '\xac\xbb,v\xc9o\xa8\x18\x89\x95\xd8K\x03AZ\xac'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. convert the string from its current encoding into UTF-8, as MongoDB only supports UTF-8 encoded strings in documents; you can use python's [string encoding functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode) for this
2. store the string as binary data in a binary type field, using the [`binary` submodule](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/binary.html#bson.binary.Binary) in PyMongo.